# If you have a parent web component with multiple child components in a tile system is it an anti-pattern for some components to share a viewmodel?

Tags: angular, typescript, mvvm

Building an angular application with a parent component that hold child components. I wish to share functionality between components without creating services for everything.

Build services and copy funcionality from all components

Answer (score 1):

as you only defined the first way is simpler to make a common class file that you can import or a service else another way is just use the child component for renderind and perform the functionality in parent and pass the processed data